# How to get saved date value from Sql Server in dateTimePicker Control in Windows Application

Tags: c#, forms, sql-server-2008, datetimepicker

I have a simple registration table of employee having column Name, Number, Email, DOB, JoinDate.
I want to populate this value in the form in respective controls, i.e Name value goes in textbox and DOB value goes in dateTimePicker control and dateTimePicker automatically select the date which is coming from DB.
I do the logics for textboxes but not have a solution for dateTimePicker Control.
I am attaching some code for reference.

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCN"].ConnectionString))
{

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from EmpRegister", con);
            con.Open();

            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.SelectCommand = cmd;
            da.Fill(dt);
            if (dt != null && dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {


                txtName.Text = dt.Rows[0]["EmpName"].ToString();
                txtPassword.Text = dt.Rows[0]["Password"].ToString();
                txtPassword.Enabled = false;
                txtUserName.Text = dt.Rows[0]["UserName"].ToString();

                txtDesignation.Text = dt.Rows[0]["EmpDesignation"].ToString();
                txtMobileNumber.Text = dt.Rows[0]["Empnumber"].ToString();
                txtEmailId.Text = dt.Rows[0]["EmpEmail"].ToString();
                bindRole();
                comboboxRole.SelectedValue = dt.Rows[0]["EmpRole"].ToString();

                dateTimePickerJoinDate.Value = Convert.ToDateTime("JoinDate");

                dateTimePickerDOB.Value = dt.Rows[0][Convert.ToDateTime(DOB)].ToString();
                dateTimePickerJoinDate.Value = dt.Rows[0][Convert.ToDateTime(JoinDate)].ToString();

                //string Gender = null;
                //if (radioButtonMale.Checked)
                //{
                  //  Gender = "Male";
                //}
                //else
                //{
                //    Gender = "Female";
                //}
                //radioButtonMale.Checked = dt.Rows[0]["Gender"].ToString();

            }

            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No Data in dt");
            }

        }
```

Please tell me how can i get the values of date in the datetimepicker control.
I am working on windows application.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try to set/get `.Value` property of DateTime Picker?

Comment: Nopes i didn't try with set/get methods. i am trying to pick the date value Direct from DB without using set/get methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ankush,
I noticed you're trying to set dateTimePickerJoinDate in two places in different ways.  The first way looks like you're trying to convert the string "JoinDate" to a date, which should throw an error.
Have you tried this syntax:

```
dateTimePickerJoinDate.Value = dt.Rows[0]["JoinDate"].ToString();
-- or
dateTimePickerJoinDate.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(dt.Rows[0]["JoinDate"]);
```

--Jim

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible to pass the date time from your sql database then convert that string to Date Time:

```
string sqlDate = dt.Rows[0]["JoinDate"].ToString();
dateTimePIckerJoinDate.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(sqlDate);
```